# Excel Macro to Change Cell Format to Currency

Tags: excel, currency, currency-formatting, vba

I have a file where a column is full of numbers, and the second column has the respective currency of each number.  I have `USD, EUR, CHF, and GBP`.

I want to create a macro that will format the number column from number to currency, and then apply the currency from the second column.

The trick to this is that I want the number column to still have numbers in it, as in the number can be added or subtracted.  Thus, I don't want a simple join of the two columns because that would make the fields text, and unable to be used in mathematical equations.

Please help if you know how.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just format the column's cells as "currency" and set the currency type?

Comment: I can, but the problem is I have a LOT of rows, and going through each one and selecting the correct currency (since there are 4 currencies to choose from) will take some time.  That's why I want to write a macro to do it for me... if I can

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while setting one of your custom formats?  You should be able to use that to get started.

Comment: It will help getting it started, but I want the computer to recognize the currency and set it that way.  If I write the macro to set the format to currency, it'll default to USD, and I have 3 other currencies, not just USD.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand your exact issue, but this will take all the values in Column A and format them as currency in Column C based upon the currency value in Column B:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim cl As Range

For Each cl In Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
   cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = cl.Value
   Select Case cl.Offset(0, 1).Value
      Case "USD"
         cl.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
      Case "EUR"
         cl.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "[$€-2] #,##0.00"
      Case "GBP"
         cl.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "[$£-809]#,##0.00"
      Case "CHF"
         cl.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "[$CHF] #,##0.00"
   End Select

Next cl

End Sub
```

If you want to change the currency types, record a macro where you set a cell to the correct currency then copy and paste that number format as needed.

Comment: It keeps using Euros and the European numberformat for me (I am Dutch) While my code definitely hits `cl.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"`

Comment: The problem seems to be that this can be different depending on your system locale. For meat that is in euro's so to change that into dollars is had to change it to `cl.NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0.00"` Other than that I have the problem that i cant seem to change `$12.000,00` (Which is the dutch comma and decimal point) to `$12,000.00` Can someone help me figure that out.